# How to Conditionally making a Karate test fail (with JavaScript)

Tags: karate

How can I make a test fail using javascript?

As per documentation this should do:

`* if(true) throw 'custom message'`

but I'm getting this error:

`findAuthDataByUserAndApp.feature:20 - javascript evaluation failed: if(true) throw 'custom message', custom message in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 9`

(What I would like to do is conditionally match response code based on __arg in a reusable feature like)

`* if(__arg.statusCode != null && responseStatus != __arg.statusCode) throw 'custom message`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, and the `throw` is just a workaround for users who insist on some "extra" message in the log. The "error" is how it is designed currently, the test fails, it just "looks" like a JS error. We recommend other patterns.

```
* def failed = true
* if (failed) karate.log('custom message')
* assert !failed
```

If you insist, I can open a feature request for a `karate.fail(condition, message)` method that would do the above. IMHO it shouldn't be used, because tests should ideally be [deterministic](https://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html).

EDIT: `karate.fail('message')` will be available in 0.9.6 final

Comment: ok, but a little bit confusing because this exact example is in the documentation https://intuit.github.io/karate/#conditional-logic

Comment: @ivangsa ok, I can confirm we will fix and update the docs in the next release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1094#issuecomment-614681204

Answer (score 1):

I found an elegant solution for my original problem:

```
* def expectedStatusCode = req.statusCode || responseStatus
* match responseStatus == expectedStatusCode
```

(sometimes the solutions is just the simpler...)

Comment: congrats :) won't this work also: `* match responseStatus == req.statusCode`

Comment: un my case req.statusCode may not be informed