# Can we append custom text with match in Karate DSL like * match city == 'Pune', 'City Name matching'

Tags: karate

Can we append custom text  with match in Karate DSL like:

- match city == 'Pune', 'City Name matching'

Here, it is trying to match whole text 'Pune City Name matching'. But I want to match only 'Pune' and need to append text like 'City Name matching'

Something like below:
Assert.assertEquals(city, "Pune", "City Name Check Completed");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not supported. You can look at [`karate.fail()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61251714/143475) for very custom needs or contribute code. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108755/143475